# Videoview not working in samsung device only for some video

Tags: android, android-videoview

I used Videoview in my app. Its working fine in all device. But for there is some link, like given one, which doesn't work in Samsung device only.
For other all device even with very low configuration, it's working fine.
Please don't share videoview example etc. Please give a logical answer.

Video Link: **[Video Link Here](http://www.tozaii.com/tozaii/toz_prod/Product_Video/1536288588video.mp4)**

```
private void play(){
        pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.buffering_video));
        pd.show();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(video_url);
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.start();

        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //close the progress dialog when buffering is done
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please post code of what you did...

Comment: Put a error listener using `videoView.setOnErrorListener();` and see if there is any error also check the logs . Also try some other video url on this just make it clear .

Comment: Which devices and which Android versions does it **not** work in?

Comment: Device - Galaxy Tab-A
Model number - SM-T355Y
OS: Marshmallow

Comment: @Kush - Did you ever resolve this issue? If so please share.